# Xcode add connection doesn't add function

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode. I've just added a button in the storyboard. I control-drag to the implementation file. The function doesn't show up in the implementation file. Strangely enough if I do a search with on the newly added function it DOES show up in the new screen in the implementation file.

How can I solve this? Because it's time consuming not being sure the function was added and not being able to add code without performing a search?

Thanks

Comment: I think I've found it. The link above was set to manual. It seems to appear when putting it on automatic :s

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for the answer: one has to put the link on automatic. If the link is set to manual control drag will not change the file on your screen. Beware that is was created though.